# How do I solve the Redshift error: "Missing data for not-null field"?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a nested JSON field that looks like this:

```
trend
{"trend":0,"abs":0,"per":null}
```

I want to query and get the values that are inside, so I have a case statement in order to get the values:

```
select
(CASE WHEN trend like '%"trend"%' THEN json_extract_path_text(trend, 'trend') ELSE NULL END)::SMALLINT,
(CASE WHEN trend like '%"abs"%' THEN json_extract_path_text(trend, 'abs') ELSE NULL END)::INTEGER,
(CASE WHEN trend like '%"per"%' THEN json_extract_path_text(trend, 'per') ELSE NULL END)::DOUBLE PRECISION
from staging_raw.table
```

The issue is in the last field `per`, because it's `null` already I am getting this error message in Redshift:

[image: Redshift Error: Missing data for not-null field]

I tried to use the clause:

```
(CASE WHEN trend like '%"per"%' and json_extract_path_text(trend, 'per') is not NULL THEN json_extract_path_text(trend, 'per')  ELSE NULL END)::DOUBLE PRECISION
```

but I still get the same error. How can this be resolved, if the source is like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I solved this:

```
 and json_extract_path_text(trend, 'p(CASE WHEN trend like '%"per"%' and json_extract_path_text(trend, 'per') !='' THEN json_extract_path_text(trend, 'per')  ELSE NULL END)::DOUBLE PRECISION
er') !=''
```

This worked because `json_extract_path_text(trend, 'per')` was not a `NULL` value but just an empty one!